# How to make the div to float on right with stacked on top of one another

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create expand/collapse section. Please find the code here. "Section 1" and "section 2" is working correctly, where as "section 3" and "Section 4" is not working. When "expand" is clicked on "section 3", I want section 1, 2 and 4 stacked on right side.

```js
function expand(id)
{   
        $('.main > div').each(function(i,item) {            
            if(i == id)
            {
                $(item).removeClass('normal');
                $(item).addClass('expand');
            }
            else
            {
                $(item).removeClass('normal');
                $(item).addClass('collapse');
            }
        }); 
}
function collapse(id)
{   
        $('.main > div').each(function(i,item) {            
            if(i == id)
            {
                $(item).removeClass('expand');
                $(item).addClass('normal');
            }
            else
            {
                $(item).removeClass('collapse');
                $(item).addClass('normal');
            }
        }); 
}
```

```css
html{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
body{width:100%;}
.main{width:98%; height:300px; border:1px solid #333}
.main > div {border:1px solid #ccc;margin:2px;}
.normal{width:45.5%;height:48%;float:left;}
.expand {width:69.7%;height:98%;float:left;position:relative;top:0;left:0}
.collapse {width:25.7%;height:60px;float:right;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;position:relative;right:0;top:auto}
.normal .btnCollapse{display:none;}
.expand .btnExpand{display:none;}
.collapse .btnCollapse{display:none;}
.collapse .btnExpand{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<div class="main">
<div class="normal">
section 1
<button class="btnExpand" onclick="expand(0)"> expand</button>
<button class="btnCollapse" onclick="collapse(0)"> collapse</button>
</div>
<div class="normal">
section 2<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(1)> expand</button>
<button class="btnCollapse"  onclick=collapse(1)> collapse</button>
</div>
<div class="normal">
section 3<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(2)> expand</button>
<button class="btnCollapse"  onclick=collapse(2)> collapse</button>
</div>
<div class="normal">
section 4<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(3)> expand</button>
<button class="btnCollapse"  onclick=collapse(3)> collapse</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a few CSS changes, and JavaScript ones as well.

**CSS :**

1. Set `position` of `main` element to `relative`.
2. Set `position` of `.expand` to `absolute`.
3. Make a class `clear` and add `clear: both;` in it.

**JS :**

1. On expanding, add `clear` class to the elements to be collapsed.
2. On collapsing, remove `clear` class from elements to be set to `normal`.

```js
var parents = $('.main > div');

function expand(id) {
  parents.eq(id).siblings().removeClass('normal').addClass('collapse clear');
  parents.eq(id).removeClass('normal').addClass('expand');
}

function collapse(id) {
  parents.eq(id).addClass('normal').removeClass('expand');
  parents.eq(id).siblings().addClass('normal').removeClass('collapse clear');
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  width: 98%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333
}

.main>div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 2px;
}

.normal {
  width: 49.5%;
  height: 48%;
  float: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.expand {
  width: 69.7%;
  height: 98%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  left: 0;
}

.collapse {
  width: 25.7%;
  height: 60px;
  float: right;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: auto;
}

.normal .btnCollapse {
  display: none;
}

.expand .btnExpand {
  display: none;
}

.collapse .btnCollapse {
  display: none;
}

.collapse .btnExpand {
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="normal">
      section 1
      <button class="btnExpand" onclick="expand(0)"> expand</button>
      <button class="btnCollapse" onclick="collapse(0)"> collapse</button>
    </div>
    <div class="normal">
      section 2<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(1)> expand</button>
      <button class="btnCollapse" onclick=collapse(1)> collapse</button>
    </div>
    <div class="normal">
      section 3<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(2)> expand</button>
      <button class="btnCollapse" onclick=collapse(2)> collapse</button>
    </div>
    <div class="normal">
      section 4<button class="btnExpand" onclick=expand(3)> expand</button>
      <button class="btnCollapse" onclick=collapse(3)> collapse</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I also applied "-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease" to the class "Expand" and "Collapse". The animation starts and stops abruptly. I want the animation on collapsing to complete then animation on expansion should start.

Comment: @Nideesh does the updated code satisfies your requirements?

Comment: Thanks, working. I changed the animation from "all 0.5 ease" to "width 0.5 ease". Because at the start of animation child div were going beyond parent border and causing scrollbars